# Como passar valores de formulário input do tipo range para variáveis definidas em JavaScript para realizar condições?

Tags: javascript, input, condição, range

Estou com precisando pegar valores de um formulário do tipo "range" e através dos valores de cada `<input>` do `<form>` quero armazenar em uma `var` do JavaScript dentro da própria página `<html>` para que dentro de uma função `verifica()` eu possa realizar condições do tipo `if` e `else`ou switch verificando um valor a partir de uma média dos valores pela quantidade de perguntas e direcionar para outra página `<html>` de acordo com os resultados.

Código do Head:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Código JS:

```
<script>  

validar = function(){

    var soma = 0;
    $('input[type=range]').each(function() {
        soma += parseInt($(this).val());
    });


    // depurando variável com da média
    soma = (soma/3);

    switch (soma) {
        case 0:
            location.href="depreop01.html";
            break;
        case 1:
            location.href="depreop02.html";
            break;
        case 2:
            location.href="depreop03.html";
            break;
        default:
            location.href="questionario.html";        
    }

        } // fim da função validar 
</script>
```

Código HTML:

```
<form name="form" target="blank">
    <label class="ui-hidden-accessible"></label>
    <p>1. PERGUNTA</p>
    <input type="range" name="fum-dep-1" id="fum-dep-1" min="0" max="10" value="10" step="1" data-highlight="true">

    <label for="slider" class="ui-hidden-accessible"></label>
    <p>2. PERGUNTA</p>
    <input type="range" name="fum-dep-2" id="fum-dep-2" min="0" max="10" value="10" step="1" data-highlight="true">

    <label for="slider" class="ui-hidden-accessible"></label>
    <p>3. PERGUNTA</p>
    <input type="range" name="fum-dep-3" id="fum-dep-3" min="0" max="10" value="10" step="1" data-highlight="true">
    <br>
    <input type="button" name="submit" onclick="validar();" value="Enviar" id="submit" />
    </form>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: já fez alguma coisa? Onde está sua dificuldade? Posta o código para vermos como  está.

Comment: Certo @NelsonAguiar

Comment: Dá uma olhada ai @NelsonAguiar o final faltou mais uma foto pq não tenho reputação ainda mas é só o <input type="submit" onclick="validar();" data-theme="b" value="Enviar" />

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485

Comment: Dá uma olhada ali se é isso mesmo  que você precisa, espero que ajude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara dá para você percorrer os inputs para fazer a soma desta forma:

```
var total = 0;
$('input[type=number]').each(function() { //number devido ao código gerado pelo jquery mobile.
    total += parseInt($(this).val());
});
```

Aqui tem um pequeno exemplo funcionando.
https://jsfiddle.net/ugrte2ys/

Quanto sua outra duvida, teria de ver ser js, sem isso fica difícil, mas você também não usou o operador de comparação no if, se vai controlar o redirecionamento no js use button e não submit, é recomendável que você pesquise sobre métodos de depuração, alguns erros você poderia ver com facilidae, aqui está o código que provavelmente funcionará.

```
 <script>
     validar = function() {
         var soma = 0;
         $('input[type=number]').each(function() { //number devido ao código gerado pelo jquery mobile.
             soma += parseInt($(this).val());
         });
         console.log(soma);
         if (soma < 45) {
            location.href = "sua_pagina";
         }
         else{
             location.href="sua_pagina"
         }

     }      
 </script>
```

Exemplo de head que funciona:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

form:

```
 <form name="myform" target="blank">
    <label class="ui-hidden-accessible"></label>
    <p>1. PERGUNTA</p>
    <input type="range" name="fum-dep-1" id="fum-dep-1" min="0" max="10" value="0">

    <label class="ui-hidden-accessible"></label>
    <p>2. PERGUNTA</p>
    <input type="range" name="fum-dep-2" id="fum-dep-2" min="0" max="10" value="0">

     <label class="ui-hidden-accessible"></label>
     <p>3. PERGUNTA</p>
     <input type="range" name="fum-dep-3" id="fum-dep-3" min="0" max="10" value="0">
     <input type="button" name="submit" onclick="validar();" value="Enviar" id="submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: Gostei da ideia, porém, não estou conseguindo chamar a função para testar os valores no <p>. Estou suspeitando que o <scritpt> não esteja sendo chamado. Como deve ficar dentro do html? Você sabe como e posso fazer para chamar uma url dentro de uma condição no mesmo script da variavel total?

Comment: Esse fragmento de código você coloca no lugar onde está sua variável soma e para chamar uma url você usa location.href="sua_url", mas todavia é sempre bom você postar seu código por que sem ver o que você fez fica difícil de dizer alguma coisa.

Comment: Nelson, ainda não conseguir reproduzir os resultas nas minhas páginas locais. Postei o código, se quiser dá uma olhada.

Comment: Editei a resposta dá uma olhada lá, só mais uma coisa tenta deixar o código sempre formatado, quase não vi seu js pois estava como texto lá em cima

Comment: Usei o código que você mandou, ele agora chama a página, mas parece que a variável soma não está somando os ranges e então sempre vai ficar abaixo da média não entrando nas outras condições. Neste exemplo tentei usar o switch para testar todas possibilidades. Reduzir o form pra facilitar o entendimento do código. Pode verificar? Atualizei os códigos na pergunta!

Comment: Dá um console.log(soma) ou alert(soma) se preferir e você verá o que está acontecendo, quando digo depurar ou debugar, como preferir, me refiro ao console e o debugger do navegador, nesse caso agora é problema de lógica com os  comandos acima você conseguirá perceber o problema.

Comment: Testei utilizar o debugger com o log e não estoura erro e sempre retorna 0, por isso, acho que tem mais algum detalhe que não está percorrendo os inputs.

Comment: Nelson, estava fazendo manutenção no código e conseguir achar a causa aparente do problema... Quando eu desativo dentro do <head> a tag script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js" no navegador volta a aparência normal sem os efeitos e então os parâmetros passam e as condições funcionam. Então, talvez agora seja verificar uma forma de validar esse .js para que funcione no mobile e tb no navegador. Vou editar o código pra mostrar como está meu head.

Comment: Quando deixo a linha do js aparece a imagem que estou anexando na depuração como erro de "concat".

Comment: esse problema é devido a incompatibilidade do jquery-mobile1.4.5 com sua versão do jquery, mude para versão 1.x  ou 2.x ou use jquery migrate plugin, quanto a soma, note que quando seu html é gerado seus inputs range já não existem mais agora é type number é só mudar na função para type=number no each() que irá pegar o valor da soma. Está editada a resposta. Espero que agora consiga resolver seu problema

Comment: E se precisar de mais ajuda quanto a incompatibilidade, acho que seria bom abrir uma nova pergunta, pois estamos saindo do escopo da sua pergunta inicial.

Comment: Bom pelo que você já me passou pela proposta da pergunta já funciona. Agora é entender porque no Smartphone aparece no log NaN. Pelo navegador já funciona. Valeu!